# How to redraw/recreate the template inside a directive on scope change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a Twitter share button directive, that changes according to the parent model

```js
app.directive('twitterShare', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-count=\"none\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-text=\"{{text}}\" data-lang=\"pt-BR\"></a>",
    scope: {
      text: '=twitterShare'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $model) {
      return $scope.$watch('text', function(value) {
         //??
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and the directive

```html
<div twitter-share="scopeModel"></div>
```

The `$scope.text` is correctly showing my `$scope.scopeModel`, but since twitter replaces the `a` element with an iframe, the element itself is lost. How can I recreate/redraw when it changes, but apply some kind of throttle, since recreating an iframe is expensive.

Tried to change it to

```js
app.directive('twitterShare', function($compile, $timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    text: '=twitterShare'
  },
  link: function($scope, element) {
    var $element;

    $element = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-count=\"none\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-text=\"{{text}}\" data-lang=\"pt-BR\"></a>";

    $scope.$watch('text', function(value) {
      if (value != null) {
        $timeout(function() {
          element.html($compile($element)($scope));
          typeof twttr !== "undefined" && twttr !== null ? twttr.widgets.load() : void 0;
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
});
```

But the second time the `$watch`'ed model changes, the `{{text}}` placeholder isn't updated. Another weird thing is that everytime the `scopeModel` changes, the `$$watchers` object keeps incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use $interpolate instead of $compile. $interpolate makes it able to deal with strings, and won't stack $$watchers like $compile does, and it's also much easier on memory and CPU usage than $compile

```js
app.directive('twitterShare', function($interpolate, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        text: '=twitterShare'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: "<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='element'></div>",
      link: function($scope, element) {
        var $element;

        $element = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-count=\"none\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-text=\"{{text}}\" data-lang=\"pt-BR\"></a>";

        $scope.$watch('text', function(value) {
          if (value != null) {
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.element = $interpolate($element)($scope);
              typeof twttr !== "undefined" && twttr !== null ? twttr.widgets.load() : void 0;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```